# sandbox-proxy container crashes shortly after starting

Tags: docker, hortonworks-sandbox, hdp

Tried to set up HDP (2.6.5 & 3.0.1) on a fresh install of Ubuntu (both 18.04.3 & 16.04).

Followed the instructions for deploying the Hortonworks Sandbox on Docker at https://www.cloudera.com/tutorials/sandbox-deployment-and-install-guide/3.html.

After running:

```
sh docker-deploy-hdp30.sh
```

both images are successfully downloaded and can be started by:

```
docker start sandbox-hdp
docker start sandbox-proxy
```

Unfortunately however, the sandbox-proxy container crashes after 2 seconds. I know this because running:

```
docker ps
```

right after starting it shows that it does run for a moment.

```
docker logs sandbox-proxy
```

returns this error message:

```
[emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "sandbox-hdp" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/http-hdp.conf:9
nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "sandbox-hdp" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/http-hdp.conf:9
```

This is essentially step 1 of the setup and deployment guide so I'm not sure what I could have done wrong. Here is output of running the deployment shell script: https://pastebin.com/FZyeqawX

Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue will be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Running the proxy-deploy.sh script produces the same result.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with the first step:

```
sh ./docker-deploy-hdp30.sh
```

I found this comment in [cloudera](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/sandbox-proxy-container-crashes-shortly-after-starting/m-p/281425/highlight/true#M209372), so I tried:

```
bash ./docker-deploy-hdp30.sh
```

and **it worked for me**!!

Answer (score 0):

can u check if port required is available? I was also observing the same but in logs I found that port is already taken, so I had to kill that process.

Comment: I checked the port but that was not the problem for me. I had to move on to setting up the Hadoop environment manually. That process took a long time as well but at least there were actually helpful error logs along the way.